# Getting kinds on features that has high confidence on classfication

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any way get a constraint on features (e.g., ear longer than 100cm and body weight>20kg and ...) or (...)) where it could say 90% guarantee it is a dog or cat? Say if we want to classify dog/cat.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a decision tree for example. These trees can have a stop criterion. For example if the leaf is too small in sample size or, and this is interesting for you, is above a pre-defined purity threshold. By discarding all the final leafs that were created due to not purity related conditions you should end up with a set of rules like you described.